# Group dictionaries to the smallest set of key values pairs possible

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I am pulling data from an API, and creating a dictionary that looks like this.

```
my_dict = {'server_name1':
               ['utah', 'california', 'idaho', 'texas'],
           'server_name2':
               ['NewYork'],
           'server_name3':
               ['idaho', 'new york', 'texas'],
           'server_name4':
               ['florida'],
           'server_name5':
               ['utah', 'california']}
```

I am trying to create maintenance groups so we only have to notify clients about maintenance one time by knowing all the servers they touch, which in turn requires knowing all the servers other customers on those servers are on. So I want to combine as many like groups as possible and I am doing this by grouping the keys that have at least one matching value as other keys. So my dictionary would go from the above to:

```
new_dict = {'server_name1, server_name2, server_name3, server_name5':
                ['utah', 'california', 'idaho', 'texas', 'newyork'],
            'server_name4':
                ['florida']}
```

I have some code that does this, but it takes several iterations of grouping, which is not great unless you know exactly how many times you have to group things to get to the smallest number of groups possible.

This is my working code.

```
new_dict = {}
for key in my_dict.iteritems():
    for key2 in my_dict.iteritems():
        if len(key[1]) > 0 and len(key2[1]) > 0:
            if key[0] != key2[0]:
                if all(x in key[1] for x in key2[1]) == True:
                    newkey = "{0}, {1}".format(key2[0],key[0])
                    servers = key[0] + ", " + key2[0]
                    states = key[1] + list(key2[1])
                    group = {servers:states}
                    new_dict.update(group)
```

Comment: `NewYork` vs `new york`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abstract behind what you want to accomplish is *finding connected components in a graph* of servers and states. We can implement a solution converting your `dict` to a graph, finding connected components and converting back to the desired format.

First, let's define the helper functions that will allow us to treat `my_dict` as a graph.

```
def get_cluster(x_to_y, y_to_x, x):
    # Implement a breadth-first search to recover all servers connected to x
    queue = [x]
    cluster = set()
    while queue:
        current = queue.pop()
        if current not in cluster:
            queue.extend({i for y in x_to_y[current] for i in y_to_x[y]})
            cluster.add(current)
    return cluster


def get_connected_parts(x_to_y):
    # We were provided a server -> state representation of the graph
    # For efficiency, we will generate a state -> server dict of edges
    y_to_x = {}

    for server, states in x_to_y.items():
        for state in states:
            if state in y_to_x:
                y_to_x[state].add(server)
            else:
                y_to_x[state] = {server}

    # We now iterate over our servers and recover their clusters
    seen = set()
    clusters = []

    for x in x_to_y:
        if x not in seen:
           cluster = get_cluster(x_to_y, y_to_x, x)
           seen |= cluster
           clusters.append(cluster)

    return clusters
```

Most of the job has now been done, the function `get_connected_parts` can be used to retrieve sets of connected servers. All that remains is to format the data. But first, let's have a look at its output.

```
my_dict = {
 'server_name1': ['utah', 'california', 'idaho', 'texas'],
 'server_name2': ['new york'],
 'server_name3': ['idaho', 'new york', 'texas'],
 'server_name4': ['florida'],
 'server_name5': ['utah', 'california']}

groups = get_connected_parts(my_dict)

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[{'server_name2', 'server_name1', 'server_name3', 'server_name5'}, {'server_name4'}]
```

Note that it does not make much sense to have keys look like `'server1, server2, server3, server5'`, because that would require that the user knows which servers are connected whenever trying to access a key. Instead, we are going to output a `new_dict` which keys are servers and values are all indirectly connected states.

```
new_dict = {}

for group in groups:
    states = list({state for server in group for state in my_dict[server]})
    for state in group:
        new_dict[state] = states
```

We can use `pprint` to check the output is correct.

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'server_name1': ['california', 'texas', 'idaho', 'utah', 'new york'],
 'server_name2': ['california', 'texas', 'idaho', 'utah', 'new york'],
 'server_name3': ['california', 'texas', 'idaho', 'utah', 'new york'],
 'server_name4': ['florida'],
 'server_name5': ['california', 'texas', 'idaho', 'utah', 'new york']}
```

Comment: You already went above and beyond, but data analysis is not what I do, and I really want to understand what is going on here. What is an edge, and can you add a few more comments to the code for my dumb ass.

Comment: Also, this absolutely does exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Ryan An edge is a connection between two nodes in a graph. If there is anything you do not understand do not hesitate to specify it in the comments, I'll add details in the answer

Comment: @Ryan as for terminology, you can find the fundamentals [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graph_theory/graph_theory_fundamentals.htm)

Comment: You're my new spirit animal. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be a "grouping" operation, *per se*.  Rather, it appears to be a graph closure or clustering task.  I recommend that you change this to a `while` logic: as long as you can merge two clusters, you continue looping on the existing data set.  You merge any two clusters whose intersection is non-empty.

One way to approach the inner iteration control is to use a `for` loop to go through all of the dict entries; merge when you find a match.  The outer loop repeats this until no matches are found.

Another way is to focus on the first entry only; look for another entry that has a non-empty overlap, and merge.  Once you can no longer merge the first entry with any other, you "retire" it: delete it from the "working" dict and append it to the "results" dict.  repeat this until the "working" dict is empty.

Does that get you moving?

---

```
working = my_dict
results = {}

while len(working) > 0:
    # Remove the first entry from the working directory; hold locally
    next_key = list(working.keys())[0]
    next_val = set(working.pop(next_key))

    # Now, go through the remaining entries in "working"
    # Each time you find one with an element in common with "next_val",
    #   pop that from "working" and merge into "next_val" and "next_key"

    # When there are no more such merges to make ...
    results[next_key] = next_val

    # ... and return to the top of the outer loop
    #   to get the next independent entry.
```

Comment: Im dumb so I have to be honest and say no. Can you give an example?

Comment: Awe, yup, that makes sense.